# EnableViewStateMac="false" why is it even an option?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

After a lot of reading about **EnableViewStateMac** and the possibility it will be removed in future .NET Frameworks I still wonder why this is an option to set to false.

I understand you should **NEVER** set it to false, but who decided it to create the option? And if someone really thought about it, **why would one set it to false at all**?

Why would you have an option to enable insecurity?

Comment: This is probably a question you need someone at Microsoft answering.

Comment: While I agree with @LasseV.Karlsen that only Microsoft guys can answer it correctly, I must remind you that developers even at Microsoft can make mistakes. I believe the original designers thought that allowing this value to be `false` isn't a big deal. Of course, now we know that's a big problem.

Answer (score 3):

This switch was created long before I joined the ASP.NET team, but I was curious about this myself and spent some time spelunking through the old bug database.  As far as I can tell, there are two main reasons it was introduced.

1. The switch was seen as potentially offering a performance benefit.  In an early preview of the .NET Framework (1.0 alpha, really), computing the MAC was indeed slow.  This was fixed before 1.0 reached RTM so that the performance difference was negligible.  However, the damage was done: the seed was planted in the early developers' minds that there might be some cases where for performance sake the MAC needs to be disabled.  This also led to a bunch of MSDN articles which suggested that disabling the MAC improves performance, and I'm *still* (in 2014!) finding and removing these articles.
2. In a web farm environment, the <machineKey> needs to be synced.  Unfortunately we don't make it easy to generate machine keys securely.  So, in the early days of ASP.NET testing, the switch existed to allow testers to do the simple thing for farm deployments rather than the right thing for farm deployments.  We're still battling this today, too: most developers use online machine key generators, which are insecure.  I'm working with the Visual Studio team to make generating and securing machine keys easier.

At the time, it was believed that the worst possible thing that could happen if the MAC was disabled is that you could XSS the site.  This turned out to be an incorrect assessment.

Finally, its removal is no longer just a possibility.  It has already been removed in our local source repositories.  The next .NET Framework update that we blast out onto the world *will* have this payload in it, but I don't have timelines for when that might be.  We're just sitting on the trigger waiting for the go-ahead. :)

Comment: Sounds interesting, nice answer Levi!

Comment: TIL that .NET 1.0 defaulted EnableViewStateMac to False!

Comment: The announcement that it was going away, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/farewell-enableviewstatemac/, says that setting it to false allowed arbitrary code execution.  I’m curious as to how, and how that wasn’t a massive bug that needed to be fixed and not just by making the option do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Initially during times of asp the HTML page used to be posted to asp pages which was totally different. This similar coding method is now termed as cross page posting. ViewState is specific to a page so if you try posting an asp.net page to another asp.net page the viewstate would be different. Now in such a situation if you have EnableViewStateMac (which means you want to verify the integrity of viewstate) set the validation would fail and cause an error. So people would disable the viewstatemac so that they can continue to program the old way, and Microsoft continued to provide this feature to have support for the legacy code.

But as you already mentioned this is a huge security risk, opening your application for all kinds of attacks.